# Unit tests for 64 bit division

Tags: unit-testing, 64-bit, integer-division

I am tasked with unit testing the 64 bit division function (which we have coded in assembler for PPC, not that that should matter).

So far, I have:

- max value div max value
- max value div min value
- max value div minus max value
- max value div zer0
- zero div max value
- 6 div 2
- 6 div -2
- -6 div 2
- -6 div -2
- 1 div 1
- 11 div 4

What am I missing to give a thorough unit testing of this new code?

Answer (score 0):

Without any knowledge of the implementation, one can chose patterns that are likely to expose *typical* sources of error, such as failures to propagate carries between bits or words, or corner cases in rounding. Typical patterns:

1. Powers of two: 2<sup>i</sup>
2. Powers of two decremented by one: 2<sup>i</sup>-1
3. Powers of two incremented by one: 2<sup>i</sup>+1
4. The sum of any two powers of two: 2<sup>i</sup> + 2<sup>j</sup>
5. The difference of any two powers of two: 2<sup>i</sup> - 2<sup>j</sup>
6. The one's complement of any of the patterns 1. through 5.
7. The two's complement of any of the patterns 1. through 5.

Obviously, there is overlap between the pattern classes, which allows for quick checking with few test vectors in the form of "smoke" tests, as well as in-depth checking with larger number of test vectors. Since division has two arguments, patterns for the divisor and dividend should also be created from different pattern classes.

In my experience, these simple patterns are surprisingly effective in weeding out bugs in all kinds of arithmetic operations including integer division. The application of such test patterns is discussed in this classical note:

N. L. Schryer, "A Test of a Computer’s Floating-Point Arithmetic Unit." Computing Science Technical Report No. 89, AT&T Bell Laboratories, February 4, 1981 [(online)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/db04/f5130fbbdb0565309defd1e7bfd953d011a5.pdf)

On my x64 machine, a test of a simple 64-bit bit-wise division implementation using all of the above pattern classes takes just over a minute with the following C code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>

int64_t v[32768]; /* FIXME: size appropriately */

#define ADDcc(a,b,cy,t0,t1) \
  (t0=(b), t1=(a), t0=t0+t1, cy=t0<t1, t0=t0)
#define ADDC(a,b,cy,t0,t1) \
  (t0=(b)+cy, t1=(a), t0+t1)

/* bit-wise non-restoring two's complement division */
void my_div_core (int64_t dividend, int64_t divisor, int64_t *quot, int64_t *rem)
{
    const int operand_bits = (int) (sizeof (int64_t) * CHAR_BIT);
    uint64_t d = (uint64_t)divisor;
    uint64_t nd = 0 - d; /* -divisor */
    uint64_t r, q = 0; /* remainder, quotient */
    uint64_t dd = d;  /* divisor */
    uint64_t cy, t0, t1;
    int i;

    q = dividend;
    r = (dividend < 0) ? (~0) : 0;  // sign-extend
    for (i = operand_bits - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if ((int64_t)(r ^ dd) < 0) {
            /* shift 128-bit quantity q:r left by 1 bit */
            q = ADDcc (q, q, cy, t0, t1);
            r = ADDC  (r, r, cy, t0, t1);
            r += dd;
            q += 0; /* record quotient bit -1 (as 0) */
        } else {
            /* shift 128-bit quantity q:r left by 1 bit */
            q = ADDcc (q, q, cy, t0, t1);
            r = ADDC  (r, r, cy, t0, t1);
            r -= dd;
            q += 1; /* record quotient bit +1 (as 1) */
        }
    }

    /* convert quotient from digit set {-1,1} to plain two's complement */
    q = (q << 1) + 1;

    /* fix up cases where we worked past a partial remainder of zero */
    if (r == d) { /* remainder equal to divisor */
        q = q + 1;
        r = 0;
    } else if (r == nd) { /* remainder equal to -divisor */
        q = q - 1;
        r = 0;
    }

    /* for truncating division, remainder must have same sign as dividend */
    if (r && ((int64_t)(dividend ^ r) < 0)) {
        if ((int64_t)q < 0) {
            q = q + 1;
            r = r - d;
        } else {
            q = q - 1;
            r = r + d;
        }
    }

    *quot = (int64_t)q;
    *rem  = (int64_t)r;
}

int64_t my_div (int64_t dividend, int64_t divisor)
{
    int64_t quot, rem;
    my_div_core (dividend, divisor, &quot, &rem);
    return quot;
}

int main (void)
{
    int64_t dividend, divisor, quot, ref;
    int i, j, patterns, idx = 0, nbrBits = sizeof (uint64_t) * CHAR_BIT;

    /* pattern class 1: 2**i */
    for (i = 0; i < nbrBits; i++) {
        v [idx] = (int64_t)((uint64_t)1 << i);
        idx++;
    }
    /* pattern class 2: 2**i-1 */
    for (i = 0; i < nbrBits; i++) {
        v [idx] = (int64_t)(((uint64_t)1 << i) - 1);
        idx++;
    }
    /* pattern class 3: 2**i+1 */
    for (i = 0; i < nbrBits; i++) {
        v [idx] = (int64_t)(((uint64_t)1 << i) + 1);
        idx++;
    }
    /* pattern class 4: 2**i + 2**j */
    for (i = 0; i < nbrBits; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < nbrBits; j++) {
            v [idx] = (int64_t)(((uint64_t)1 << i) + ((uint64_t)1 << j));
            idx++;
        }
    }
    /* pattern class 5: 2**i - 2**j */
    for (i = 0; i < nbrBits; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < nbrBits; j++) {
            v [idx] = (int64_t)(((uint64_t)1 << i) - ((uint64_t)1 << j));
            idx++;
        }
    }
    patterns = idx;
    /* pattern class 6: one's complement of pattern classes 1 through 5 */
    for (i = 0; i < patterns; i++) {
        v [idx] = ~v [i];
        idx++;
    }
    /* pattern class 7: two's complement of pattern classes 1 through 5 */
    for (i = 0; i < patterns; i++) {
        v [idx] = -v [i];
        idx++;
    }
    patterns = idx;

    for (i = 0; i < patterns; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < patterns; j++) {
            dividend = v [i];
            divisor  = v [j];
            /* exclude cases with undefined results: division by zero, overflow*/
            if (!((divisor == 0LL) || 
                  ((dividend == (-0x7fffffffffffffffLL - 1LL)) && (divisor == -1LL)))) {
                quot = my_div (dividend, divisor);
                ref = dividend / divisor;
                if (quot != ref) {
                    printf ("error @ (%016llx, %016llx): quot = %016llx  ref=%016llx\n", 
                            dividend, divisor, quot, ref);
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf ("64-bit division: test passed\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In addition to the above pattern tests, you would want to add *targeted* pseudo-random test vectors, in particular focusing on the following scenarios:

1. Small divisors
2. Small quotients
3. Small remainders

A suitable way of generating test vectors for classes 2. and 3. is by constructing the dividend by multiplication (pick a small random multiplier) and multiplication plus addition (pick a small random addend) from a random divisor.

In general, modern computers are fast enough to allow between 2<sup>32</sup> and 2<sup>48</sup> test cases depending on the speed of the system and speed of the reference implementation. You would want to use that large a number of pattern-based, targeted random, and purely random text vectors to have a reasonable chance of creating a correct 64-bit division. Let the tests run for a day, or at least overnight.

Using a large number of random test vectors requires a high-quality PRNG (pseudo-random number generator). Professor George Marsaglia's [KISS64](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.lang.fortran/qFv18ql_WlU/IK8KGZZFJx4J) would be something of a minimal standard:

```c
/*
  From: geo <gmars...@gmail.com>
  Newsgroups: sci.math,comp.lang.c,comp.lang.fortran
  Subject: 64-bit KISS RNGs
  Date: Sat, 28 Feb 2009 04:30:48 -0800 (PST)

  This 64-bit KISS RNG has three components, each nearly
  good enough to serve alone.    The components are:
  Multiply-With-Carry (MWC), period (2^121+2^63-1)
  Xorshift (XSH), period 2^64-1
  Congruential (CNG), period 2^64
*/

static uint64_t kiss64_x = 1234567890987654321ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_c = 123456123456123456ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_y = 362436362436362436ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_z = 1066149217761810ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_t;

#define MWC64  (kiss64_t = (kiss64_x << 58) + kiss64_c, \
                kiss64_c = (kiss64_x >> 6), kiss64_x += kiss64_t, \
                kiss64_c += (kiss64_x < kiss64_t), kiss64_x)
#define XSH64  (kiss64_y ^= (kiss64_y << 13), kiss64_y ^= (kiss64_y >> 17), \
                kiss64_y ^= (kiss64_y << 43))
#define CNG64  (kiss64_z = 6906969069ULL * kiss64_z + 1234567ULL)
#define KISS64 (MWC64 + XSH64 + CNG64)
```